# Spring WebFlux Proxy a Request to Another Server using WebClient CodecException: No suitable writer found for part: zip

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am trying to proxy a request to another server. I am using Spring web flux and I have an object of type `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest`  that I extract the multipart/form-data body received from using `serverRequest.multipartData()` method.

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> uploadItems(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
        return catalogService
                .uploadItems(serverRequest.multipartData()));

    }
```

After that I use `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient` to send a request to another server. The object returned from the `serverRequest.multipartData()` method is of type `Mono<MultiValueMap<String,Part>>`.

```java
 public Mono<ServerResponse> uploadItems(Mono<MultiValueMap<String, Part>> itemsMono) {
        return webClient
                .post()
                .uri(catalogDestination.getUploadItemsUrl())
                .body(itemsMono, MultiValueMap.class)
                .exchange();

    }
```

The following error is shown when I send the request:

```java
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: No suitable writer found for part: zip
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageWriter.encodePart(MultipartHttpMessageWriter.java:299) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageWriter.lambda$encodePartValues$4(MultipartHttpMessageWriter.java:252) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:367) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8134) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:441) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8134) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:207) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:80) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8134) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany.subscribe(MonoSendMany.java:81) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.1.RELEASE.jar:0.9.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.ignoreDone(MonoIgnoreThen.java:190) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreInner.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.FutureMono$FutureSubscription.operationComplete(FutureMono.java:188) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.1.RELEASE.jar:0.9.1.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:604) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.trySuccess(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:48) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeSuccess(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:715) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:270) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.removeBytes(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:350) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doWriteBytes(AbstractEpollChannel.java:370) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel.writeBytes(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:260) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel.doWriteSingle(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:471) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel.doWrite(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:429) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:931) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.flush0(AbstractEpollChannel.java:514) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:898) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1384) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:727) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.flush(LoggingHandler.java:265) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:727) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:533) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:125) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:358) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$2100(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:56) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1150) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1073) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:510) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:413) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Spring Framework are you using?

Try using `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters`

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> uploadItems(Mono<MultiValueMap<String, Part>> itemsMono) {
    return Mono.from(itemsMono)//
        .flatMap(im -> webClient//
            .post()//
            .uri(catalogDestination.getUploadItemsUrl())//
            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(im))//
            .exchange());
}
```